# Uncategorized (Xcode): Exited with status code 1

Tags: flutter, dart

The iOS device fails to start. Does anyone know what the reason is?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            6.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Exited with status code 1

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

```
$flutter doctor:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 13.4 22F5037d darwin-x64, locale zh-Hans-CN) 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc1) 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3) 
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web 
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2) 
[✓] Connected device (4 available) [✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

```
Xcode version : 14.3
```

Comment: do you test this command?

`pod deintegrate;pod install`

in your project ios folder?

Comment: getting same error, no idea what to do

Comment: Did you find a solution for this error?

Comment: flutter clean works for me

Answer (score 0):

Moving the project to a folder without iCloud synchronization was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what fixed the issue is that I run a bash script on the Pre-run stage in iOS scheme.

I just modified it a bit and it seemed to work okay. Not sure if the script was the issue though, as I have other projects with the same thing and they run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

```
rm ios/Podfile
```

**Step 2:**

Upgrade your Packages:

```
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
```

**Step 3:**

Update your Podfile:

```
cd ios
pod install --repo-update
```

**Step 4:**

Run your Project

```
flutter run
```

I hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Mayne start with running the following command to see more detailed logs

```
flutter run -v
```

and then :

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios
```